# How do I get a scala macro to replace a method call

Tags: scala, scala-macros

How do I get a scala macro to replace a method call?

My goal is to create a trait called `ToStringAdder`. Supposing I have an object `x` with this trait, then when I call `x.add(any)` I want the macro to actually call `x.add(any, string)` where the string is a string representation of the AST. (This is so that I can have nice `tostring` when 'any' is a function).

- I've written the macros given in the documentation
  http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html,
- Read http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/self-cleaning-macros.html
- Read the pdfs http://scalamacros.org/paperstalks/2013-04-22-LetOurPowersCombine.pdf.
- I've looked at the code in https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/retronym/macrocosm/Macrocosm.scala
- And the code in    https://github.com/pniederw/expecty/tree/master/src/main/scala/org/expecty,
  but I'm sad to say I didn't Grok it all
- I have had a look at the scaladoc, but...woo..that's complex... I suspect that I would need some significant time to get up to speed with how the compiler works.

With the exception of Expecty all of these examples I have seen are effectively using static method calls: the object that the macro is called on is not used.
Expecty has the following method, which gives me a clue about how to detect the 'implicit this', but I couldn't find a way to reference it in a reify call.

```
 private[this] def recordAllValues(expr: Tree): Tree = expr match {
    case New(_) => expr // only record after ctor call
    case Literal(_) => expr // don't record
    // don't record value of implicit "this" added by compiler; couldn't find a better way to detect implicit "this" than via point
    case Select(x@This(_), y) if getPosition(expr).point == getPosition(x).point => expr
    case _ => recordValue(recordSubValues(expr), expr)
  }
```

So how do I go about replacing the call to the object that the macro has been called on. The code I have at the moment is below, and it is the code in the reify call that needs to be sorted

```
trait ToStringAdder {
  def add(param: Any): Any = macro ToStringAdder.toStringAndValueImpl
  def add(param: Any, toStringBasedOnAST: String): Any ; //This is the actual method I want the above method call to be replaced by
}

object ToStringAdder {
  def toStringAndValueImpl(c: Context)(param: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    val paramRep = show(param.tree)
    val paramRepTree = Literal(Constant(paramRep))
    val paramRepExpr = c.Expr[String](paramRepTree)
    //need to put something here 
     reify { c.someMethodCall("something to represent the method any", param.splice, paramRepExpr.splice ) }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice question if I understand it correctly. I believe the point is that with a toString on a `Function` that returns a unique AST you can implement an equality operator on `Function`s.  One could then do awesome things like not worrying about duplication of functions in a `List` - just call `toSet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get `Tree` for your `ToStringAdder` instance as `c.prefix`.

Try this:

```
reify { c.Expr[ToStringAdder](c.prefix.tree).splice.add(param.splice, c.literal(paramRep).splice) }
```

Proof it works:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import reflect.macros.Context

trait ToStringAdder {
  def add(param: Any): Any = macro ToStringAdder.toStringAndValueImpl
  def add(param: Any, toStringBasedOnAST: String): Any ; //This is the actual method I want the above method call to be replaced by
}

object ToStringAdder {
  def toStringAndValueImpl(c: Context)(param: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    val paramRep = show(param.tree)
    reify { (c.Expr[ToStringAdder](c.prefix.tree)).splice.add(param.splice, c.literal(paramRep).splice) }
  }
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import reflect.macros.Context
defined trait ToStringAdder
defined module ToStringAdder

scala> class ToStringAdder1 extends ToStringAdder {
     |   def add(param: Any, toStringBasedOnAST: String): Any = s"param: $param \ntoStringBasedOnAST: $toStringBasedOnAST"
     | }
defined class ToStringAdder1

scala> new ToStringAdder1().add( (i: Int) => i*2 )
res0: Any =
param: <function1>
toStringBasedOnAST: ((i: Int) => i.*(2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I get the message "value add is not a member of org.autotdd.scalamacros.ToStringAdder". And the control/space code insight doesn't show me any options for add. Do I need to type cast or something?

Comment: @StaveEscura: I've added code example to my answer. There is a error in your code: `c.Expr[Unit]` instead of `c.Expr[Any]` as result type of `toStringAndValueImpl`.